# Get all functions that exists in lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

i need get all functions from lodash. Someting like

```
_.filter(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(_), val => _.iFunction(val))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure what your use case is but you could do this

```
const _ = require("lodash");

const functions = _.filter(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(_), val => {
  return _.isFunction(_[val])
});

console.log(functions);
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to import the lodash library and do `Object.keys()` in conjunction with the `filter` operation to find only the lodash function, something like below:

```js
var functions = Object.keys(_).filter((key) => typeof _[key] === 'function');
console.log(functions);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

The reason your code was not working was because you were checking the name of the property as it is a function or not. Instead, you need to check if the property declaration is a function type or not using `_[val]`:

```js
console.log(_.filter(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(_), val => _.isFunction(_[val])))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/lodash@4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: `_.VERSION` is not a function

Comment: @NinoFiliu now it will return only the function types

Answer (score 0):

Lodash has a [page](https://lodash.com/docs) on their [official website](https://lodash.com) that lists all the available functions and properties. You can retrieve the page and then extract the content of that page from their [official Github](https://github.com/lodash) account by using the JavaScript [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) and assign the retrieved data to a variable say, `data` using [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

You can now use regex to filter all the functions and properties from the page and assign it to a variable say, `x`.

A list of all the functions as well as properties of lodash are now available as an array in the variable `x`.

---

Check and run the following Code Snippet for a practical example of the above approach:

```js
const list = document.querySelector('#lodashFuncs ul');

async function getLodashFuncs() {
  let response = await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lodash/lodash.com/master/docs/4.17.15.html");
  let data = await response.text();
  return data;
}

getLodashFuncs().then(data => {
 const x = data.match(/(?<=\/a><code>).*?(?=<\/code><\/h3)/g);
  x.forEach(e=> {
   list.innerHTML += `<li>${e}</li>`
  })
  
});
```

```html
<div id="lodashFuncs">
  <ul></ul>
</div>
```

---

Do note that this approach isn't exactly the "best way" to do this and I would definitely recommend filtering through the object's property list using a combination of the [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method and the [Object.getOwnPropertyNames()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) method as shown in the other answers.